# Clojure: equivalent of "do" from Common Lisp

Tags: clojure, lisp, common-lisp

Newbie Lisp question, sorry for the ignorance.

What is the equivalent of Common Lisp's `do` in Clojure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clojure avoids these kind of sequential binding forms, but the same functionality can be expressed with `while` or `loop` - the first example from the [CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_do.htm) in each style:

```
;; common lisp version
(do ((temp-one 1 (1+ temp-one))
       (temp-two 0 (1- temp-two)))
      ((> (- temp-one temp-two) 5) temp-one)) =>  4

;; clojure, while
(let [temp-one (atom 1)
      temp-two (atom 0)]
  (while (> (- @temp-one @temp-two) 5)
     (swap! temp-one inc)
     (swap! temp-two dec))
  @temp-one)

;; clojure, loop
(loop [temp-one 1 temp-two 0]
  (if (> (- temp-one temp-two) 5)
    temp-one
    (recur (inc temp-one) (dec temp-two))))
```